# PHP calculator, isset problems

Tags: php, calculator, isset

Hey guys I made PHP calculator and little problem has occurred, it says this :

> Notice: Undefined variable: `vysledek` in
>   `C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\cviceni_06\Danko.php` on line 64

line 64 is at the end of code " echo $vysledek; "

can you help me to solve it please?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['calculate'] ))
    {
        $operator=$_POST['operator'];
        if($operator=="+")
        {
            $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
            $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
            $vysledek= $num1+$num2;
        }
        if($operator=="-")
        {
            $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
            $num2 = $_POST['num2']; 
            $vyslede2= $num1-$num2;
        }
        if($operator=="*")
        {
            $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
            $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
            $vysledek =$num1*$num2;
        }
        if($operator=="/")
        {
            $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
            $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
            $vysledek= $num1/$num2;
        }
        if($operator=="/")
        {
            $num2 == 0;
            $vysledek= "Nulou dělit nelze";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="cs-CZ"> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="generator" content="Prace"/> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="web.css"/>
        <title>úkol</title> 
    </head> 
    <body>

        <div id="web">
            <h1>Kalkulačka</h1>
            <h2>návod</h2>
            <p>Zadej číslo do obou políček a zvol znaménko, poté klikni na tlačítko "Počítat". Číslo nesmí obsahovat jednotku nebo desetinná místa. Musí to být přirozené číslo, také nesmíš dělit nulou.</p>
            <form method="post">
                <div id="num1">Zadej první číslo <input name="num1" type="text"/ id="xnum1"></div>
                <div id="selector">Vyber znaménko <select name="operator" id="xselector"></div>
                    <option>+</option>
                    <option>*</option>
                    <option>-</option>
                    <option>/</option>
                </select>
                <div id="num2">Zadej druhé číslo <input name="num2" type="text" id="xnum2"/></div>         
                <div id="submit">Stiskni po zadání čísel <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Počítat" id="xsubmit"/></div>
            </form>
            <?php 
                if (isset($_POST["num1"]) && ($_POST["num2"]));
                {
                    echo $vysledek;
                } 
            ?>
         </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Add `$vysledek = "";` at the very beginning of the script

Comment: Clearly none of your if statements are resolving true where you are actually setitng that variable.

Comment: You got a bunch of ifs there. It seems that either `$_POST['calculate']` is not set, or `$_POST['operator']` doesn't match any of the listed operators.

Comment: Phate01 Thanks mate, solved it

Comment: Also `if (isset($_POST["num1"]) && ($_POST["num2"]));` Should probably be `if (isset($_POST["num1"]) && isset($_POST["num2"]));`

Answer (score 0):

`$vyslede` wasn't set.

- You can use a default value for it
- or Complain that an invalid operator was used.